# How to access another components state without rendering that state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

After user logs in, I want to display the name in the header. Ive been reading about how to pass props but what I saw was when you access another components state from another component WHICH again you render insight that other component. How can I access another ones state without rendering the other component? Here I don't want to render Header Component insight my Login component and wonder

1. Here I redirect so I can pass in the state (but since I am redirecting to '/' which is Home Component and not Header Component, I still don't know how to access it in component header.
2. If I wasn't using redirect, how would I pass it to another one?

   ```
          class Header extends React.Component {
             render () {   
               return (
                   <header>
                     <nav>
                       <p className="menuButton"><Link to='/'>Home</Link></p>
                       <p className="menuButton"><Link to='/login'>Login</Link></p>
                      </nav>
                   </header>
                )
              }
           }
   ```

login component:

```
    class Login extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
                this.state = {
                    username:'',
                    email: '',
                    password: ''
                }
                this.loginFunc = this.loginFunc.bind(this)
            }
       loginFunc(){
          ... getting user data ...
          this.setState({
                username:response.firstname
          })
        ...
         history.push('/', { username: response.firstname });
         history.go('/');
       }
   }
```

Comment: It is impossible. In order to get the data to login you gotta have the header render on the page as well. unless you use something like, flux, redux to have a big shareable state.

Comment: You should use state managers like redux, flux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either have a parent React component in which you keep track of the state 
 of both Header and Login components and pass the state through props, **or** you could use state management libraries such as [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/) or implement your own PubSub mechanism. You simply can't access other components' states without the use of a parent component within vanilla React as React uses a unidirectional data flow.

I'd recommend looking into state management libraries, but if you insist on using option one you would do the following:

1. Create a parent component in which you keep track of state. This component renders both the Header and Login components. Pass a function down to the Login component (which we'll call updateState), so the Login component can call it when a user logs in.
2. Have the Login component update the state in the parent component by calling the updateState() function passed down from the Parent component - with the data received from the Login action.
3. Re-render Header component with new state from Parent component that was altered by calling updateState().

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I have a component for both login and the header, could I still pass the header to my App component (that is the one that renders home component and header component). I can't just render header and login together but leave the rest of the app without a header.

Comment: You should be able import/require your Header component in your App component yes. But the way I understand your setup why not create the updateState function from my example in your App component and store the state there? Pass down the updateState function using props to your Login component and call the function when the user logs in. Next pass the state from the App component down to your Header component also using props.

Comment: Can I do that if Im not rendering Login insight App component too? My App renders Header and Main, Main is where I have my <Route/>

Comment: Take a look a [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbq7uev9/). This wont work in your browser, but it should give you an idea of what I mean.